# How to minimize one application using c# or python?

Tags: c#, python, process, window, minimize

How can I minimize Microsoft Speech Recognition:

[image: the one on the top]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/library/media/1033/windowsvista/images/features/bov_speechrec2.png))</sub>

using C# or python?

Comment: Define minimize:  hide the window?  Show it in the taskbar (notice that window has no 'minimize' button)?

Comment: Hide de window :)
This app on windows7 has that minimize!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C#:

Using `System.Diagnostics.Process` you can select the process when it's running. From there you can get the MainWindow Handle at `.MainWindowHandle` and then call the windows API to minimize the application.

Unfortunately I do not know the specifics for that call, you'd have to google it.

Comment: This should only work if the process has been started via `Process.Start()`.

Comment: You sure, I was certain you could locate existing processes with the `Process` class. I.e: `Process.GetProcessesByName(string)` which gets a list of processes by name, or by `Process.GetProcesses()` which gets all processes on the local computer.